# compare two columns of data by key in separate table

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two tables in excel, I want compare if the two min and max columns are a match, the two keys are DivApt and ID. If they match, assign yes, otherwise no.

Table 1:

```
A       B         C         D
DivApt  ID          MIN      MAX    
1600202 68645032054 1374     1374   
1600202 65162062750 1873     1873   
1600202 406036501   740      740
```

Table 2:

```
A       B         C         D
DivApt  ID           MIN    MAX
1600202 456224030       0   0
1600202 30142085140     0   0
1600202 60758077305     0   0
```

I have tried vlookup and match function and failed, any suggestion?

Comment: The keys are not related in your sample. Could you increase your samples providing instances where the min & max don't match and the output you're looking for from those keys?

Comment: @Jerry I updated the DiveApt, basically I want check if the same ID'S min(max) value are the same.

Comment: Should 'yes' be put both in the Min and the Max columns?

Comment: @Jerry compare separately: min vs min,max vs max. "no" for unmatched.

Comment: Wait, there's something I think that needs to be confirmed. You want to see if the Min of, for example, `1600202 68645032054` in Table 1 and `1600202 68645032054` in Table 2 are the same? Then compare their Max? Can a key combination appear twice in the same table?

Comment: @Jerry 1st, yes. 2nd they only appear once in the table

Comment: Okay, so now, where should 'yes' or 'no' appear? In a new table (do you have a table with the keys already)? To the right of the max column of Table 1? Of Table 2 perhaps instead? Both tables?

Comment: @Jerry it is the best to combine the info of table 2 into table 1 and add another yes/no column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you think it is best to combine the two tables, then that's what I'll suggest.

1. Copy/paste Table 2 under Table 1:

   [image]

   [image]
2. Run a PivotTable (Under Insert tab), and pick the Tabular form after putting all fields into 'Row Labels':

   [image]
3. Remove sub-totals:

   [image]
4. And then, you can use a formula like this to do the comparison:

   [image]

As you can see, the PivotTable already groups the codes and when there is a dissimilarity, it will have a blank cell by default which can be used by the formula to check for differences.

The formula is:

```
=IF($B4<>"",IF($B5<>"","Yes",""),IF(C4<>C3,"No","Yes"))
```